# How does html5 video tag works? Is there any way to see how it is implemented

Tags: html, reactjs

I am developing an application where I need to display some animation in the canvas along with the video as a separate element, for the same I need to maintain the synchronisation between two DOM elements very precisely.

I was thinking of playing the animation as video tag plays the video. Is there any way I could see how the html5 video tag is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, each browser can have their own implementation of the video tag. Besides of that, they will try their best to follow some rules specified by w3.org

This is the video tag draft:

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#video

If yout want to sync something with a video you will want to use some video tag events:

https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Answer (score 0):

A [`timeupdate` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) can be set on the video which will allow you to synchronize other elements on the page with the video as it plays. Video elements have [many other events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Events) in addition to timeupdate, such as `play`, `pause`, and `seeking`.
The implementation of video elements will differ depending on the browser and may not be completely public, such as how they work with [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management).